# Magento2 not executing InstallSchema.php or UpgradeSchema.php

Tags: magento2, database, setup-script

I've created a custom module, and I see the row in the `setup_module` table. When I change my version and run `magento setup:upgrade`, the version number updates as well. However, the table I defined is not being created. I also see the new module enabled in `app/etc/config.php`

I tried installing a [module](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-external-links) written by Magento, but I still see the same behavior - row is in `setup_module` but table does not exist.

I tried deleting the row from `setup_module` table and rerun `magento setup:upgrade` to execute `InstallSchema.php`, but the database tables aren't created even though the row is created `setup_module` again.

I also tried incrementing the version number and try UpgradeSchema.php, but it doesn't execute even though row in `setup_module` is updated.

I introduced errors in both `InstallSchema.php` and `UpgradeSchema.php`, but `magento setup:upgrade` doesn't does not output the error messages.

I also tried recreating the installation, and ensuring the file permissions were correct (owned by `magento:www-data`). Any other ideas?

I'm using v2.0.7 CE provided by DigitalOcean.

```
<?php
namespace Test\Project\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        // Get tables
        $tableName = $installer->getTable('test_module');

        // Create table
        $table = $installer->getConnection()
        ->newTable($tableName)
        ->addColumn(
            'id',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            [
            'identity' => true,
            'unsigned' => true,
            'nullable' => false,
            'primary' => true
            ],
            'ID'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'title',
            Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
            'Title'
        )
        ->setOption('type', 'InnoDB')
        ->setOption('charset', 'utf8');

        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        $installer->endSetup();
    } // close function install()
}
```

Comment: the module is enabled? try run bin/magento module:status. If not run bin/magento module:enable:<module_name>

Comment: @95623 yes, the module is enabled. I see it in `setup_module` table as well as `etc/config.php` with value of  `1`

Comment: try to delete all tables created by the module and downgrade/remove the module version on 'setup_module' table and re run setup:upgrade

Comment: @95623 the module doesn't create any database tables in the first place...so there is nothing to delete. That's the main problem. Even if I put errors in InstallSchema.php and UpgradeSchema.php, and run `setup:upgrade`, it doesn't output any errors. It's as if those files aren't being read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by disabling all the caches via the admin and re-installing the module.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the following thats works for me. please check.

```
delete from setup_module where  module ='module_name';
sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `package name` was wrong. After replacing by right `package name` issue is fixed.

```
namespace Package_Name\Module_Name\Setup;
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently this way seems to be deprecated. Additionally to have entry in `setup_module` You have to have entered version in `module.xml`

```
 <module name="Vendor_module" setup_version="1.0.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete your module in **setup_module** then retry.